# Unicode string and TStringStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Delphi 2009 and above uses unicode strings for their default string type. To my understanding  unicode char is actually 16 bit value or 2 bytes (note: I understand there is possibility of 3 or 4 bytes char, but let's consider the most usual case). However I found that TStringStream is not very reliable to manipulating this strings. For example, TStringStream.Size property returns the length of the string, while I think it should return the byte count of the contained string. Okay, you can adjust it on your own, but the thing that really confused me the most is: TStringStream does not read from or write to a buffer reliably.

Please check the following code (it's a DUnit test and always fail). Please let me know where the problem is (I was using D2010 when testing the code).

```
procedure TestTCPackage.TestStringStream;
const
  cCount = 10;
  cOrdMaxChar = Ord(High(Char));
var
  B: Pointer;
  SW, SR: TStringStream;
  T: string;
  i, j, k : Integer;
  vStrings: array [0..cCount-1] of string;
begin
  RandSeed := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to cCount - 1 do
  begin
    j := Random(100) + 1;
    SetLength(vStrings[i], j);
    for k := 1 to j do
      // fill string with random char (but no #0)
      vStrings[i][k] := Char(Random(cOrdMaxChar-1) + 1);
  end;

  for i := 0 to cCount - 1 do
  begin
    SW := TStringStream.Create(vStrings[i]);
    try
      GetMem(B, SW.Size * SizeOf(Char));
      try
        SW.Read(B^, SW.Size * SizeOf(Char));

        SR := TStringStream.Create;
        try
          SR.Write(B^, SW.Size * SizeOf(Char));
          SR.Position := 0;

          // check the string in the TStringStream with original value
          Check(SR.DataString = vStrings[i]);
        finally
          SR.Free;
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(B);
      end;
    finally
      SW.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Note: I already tried to use an instance of TMemoryStream as intermediary from reading/writing the buffer and use CopyFrom of the TStringStream to read the content of that TMemoryStream with same failing effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557358/converting-an-ansistring-to-a-unicode-string) (and thanks to Serg who provided the answer to that question) and Barry Kelly's answer, I have found the problem. TStringStream is actually using ASCII/ansistring encoding by default. So even if your default string type is unicode, unless you spesifically tell it to, it won't use unicode encoding. Personally I think it's strange. Maybe for making it easier to convert old codes.

So you have to ***specifically set the encoding*** of the TStringStream to TEncoding.Unicode to manipulate unicode string properly.

Here is my modified code which passes DUnit test is:

```
procedure TestTCPackage.TestStringStream;
const
  cCount = 10;
  cOrdMaxChar = Ord(High(Char));
var
  B: Pointer;
  SW, SR: TStringStream;
  i, j, k : Integer;
  vStrings: array [0..cCount-1] of string;
begin
  RandSeed := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to cCount - 1 do
  begin
    j := Random(100) + 1;
    SetLength(vStrings[i], j);
    for k := 1 to j do
      // fill string with random char (but no #0)
      vStrings[i][k] := Char(Random(cOrdMaxChar-1) + 1);
  end;

  for i := 0 to cCount - 1 do
  begin
    SW := TStringStream.Create(vStrings[i], ***TEncoding.Unicode***);
    try
      GetMem(B, SW.Size);
      try
        SW.ReadBuffer(B^, SW.Size);

        SR := TStringStream.Create('', ***TEncoding.Unicode***);
        try
          SR.WriteBuffer(B^, SW.Size);
          SR.Position := 0;

          // check the string in the TStringStream with original value
          Check(SR.DataString = vStrings[i]);
        finally
          SR.Free;
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(B);
      end;
    finally
      SW.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Last note: Unicode does bite! :D

Answer (score 5):

Unicode strings aren't for data storage; use `TBytes` for that. `TStringStream` uses its associated encoding (the `Encoding` property) for encoding strings passed in with `WriteString`, and decoding strings read out with `ReadString` or the `DataString` property.

Comment: Actually the code is not about data storage, but after I read you answer and another post, I have found the problem. It's that TStringStream by default is using ASCII/ansistring. Thank you!