# How to copy HTML Formatted text As HTML to ClipBoard in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, clipboard, firemonkey, copy-paste

Using Delphi FireMonkey, I need to copy HTML formatted string to the clipboard in Delphi so that other application pasting it will see it as HTML.

I already trying to copy simple text through a hidden Memo component and it work but is copied as simple text. I need HTML format copy. Having it as text, when pasting in any rich text program it shows all the HTML tags instead of formatted text.

My Current approach for copying text to clipboard is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourceText: string;
begin
  SourceText := 'This is a <b>bold</b> html line';
  //I can use TMemo to copy it to clipboard like:
  Memo1.lines.Text := SourceText;
  Memo1.SelectAll;
  memo1.CopyToClipboard;
end;
```

But the problem is that if I paste the text copied on clipboard in Microsoft word it will be pasted as:

- "This is a `<b>bold</b>` html line". I want and it should be like:
- This is a **bold** html line

**Note:** I have read other discussions about how it can be done in windows but I need a Firemonkey solution for a cross platform application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We don't know what you are copying from, or pasting in to. We have no details about your code. Please take the [tour] to learn how to get the most out of this site, and then edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I updated the question accordingly with an example.

Comment: There is not going to be a simple answer here. On Windows you probably want to put rtf and html in the clipboard. I expect that will take some bespoke coding on your part.

Comment: I have a solution for you. Once the question is reopened, I will publish. This is a single function CopyHtmlToClipboard to do the job.

Comment: @fpiette Thanks. Yes please. I desperately need this. I have not closed the question and don't know how to reopen it.

Comment: @HilalSoftware Read the comments... You question has been closed with reason "needs details or clarity". To have it reopened, you must edit it and add details and clarity (I already edited and added a little bit of clarity). Closing and reopening questions on StackOverflow is done with voting. You'll find who voted to close your question in the blue area above your question. Now you have to wait for your question to be reopened. I already voted for that. On StackOverflow you absolutely need to follow the rules or your questions are rejected. Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @fpiette Thanks for guidance. I already edited and added detail after it was closed. Blues area don't show to me who closed the question. I am Delphi programmer since Delphi 1 and my rule of thumb is that if a problem is general enough then some smart developer already knows the solution; I need to search and ask properly. Thanks for editing. Now question seems to be fairly obvious and clear. StackOverflow rules and structure is very good and I am waiting for question to be opened.

Comment: @fpiette Thanks. Waiting for your guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To copy data to the clipboard in a cross platform way with FireMonkey is done thru the interface `IFMXExtendedClipboardService` that is obtained by calling the platform service:

```
var
    Svc      : IFMXExtendedClipboardService;
begin
    if not TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXExtendedClipboardService, Svc) then 
        Exit;  // Not clipboard supported
    // Code using the interface
```

This interface has methods to copy/get text/images to/from clipboard: `SetText`, `GetText`, `SetImage`, `GetImage`.

For other kind of data, the user must register the data format and then write/read data to/from clipboard: `RegisterCustomFormat`, `IsCustomFormatRegistered`, `UnregisterCustomFormat`, `HasCustomFormat`, `GetCustomFormat`, `SetCustomFormat`.

In your question, you say you want to copy HTML formatted data to the clipboard. This can be translated to register the HTML format, create a stream with your data and call SetCustomFormat passing the format and stream.

Any format can be used and transmitted to/from the clipboard using the above mentioned interface methods. The code below takes the stream `stream` and copy his content to the clipboard using `ClipFormat`:

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(
                IFMXExtendedClipboardService, Svc) then begin
    if not Svc.IsCustomFormatRegistered(ClipFormat) then
        Svc.RegisterCustomFormat(ClipFormat);
    Svc.SetCustomFormat(ClipFormat, Stream);
end;
```

A format must be registered only once hence the call to `IsCustomFormatRegistered` to prevent calling `RegisterCustomFormat` more than once.

The name of the format is a simple string and can be anything. Copying and pasting applications must agree on the format name and the data format (The way the data is written in the stream).

Writing HTML formatted data may be difficult because of styling. Taking just a simple copy of an complete HTML document will probably not render it correctly because of styles.

If you transfer data thru the clipboard between two of your applications, you can do whatever you want. But transferring data between your application and another (You mentioned Microsoft Word in your question) is much more difficult.

In Microsoft products and all others on the Windows platform, the HTML format in the clipboard is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767917(v=vs.85)).

The example you give in your question once properly formatted looks like this:

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:00000144
EndHTML:00000218
StartFragment:00000167
EndFragment:00000205
StartSelection:00000167
EndSelection:00000205
<!DOCTYPE><HTML><BODY><P>This is a <b>bold</b> html line</P></BODY></HTML>
```

The actual string is as above, with a CRLF at the end of each line. The format name is "HTML format".

You see the sentence `This is a <b>bold</b> html line` must be surrounded by HTML tags to form a valid complete HTML document, and be preceded by a header made of a number of `keyword:value` pairs. The values are offset if the string. The keywords are quite self explanatory. The string is UTF8 which can be reduced to ANSI if you use HTML entities to represent special characters.

I wrote a function to build the entire string:

```
function FormatHtmlForClipboard(const HtmlSrc : UTF8String) : UTF8String;
const
    Header = 'Version:0.9'             + #13#10 +
             'StartHTML:00000000'      + #13#10 +
             'EndHTML:00000000'        + #13#10 +
             'StartFragment:00000000'  + #13#10 +
             'EndFragment:00000000'    + #13#10 +
             'StartSelection:00000000' + #13#10 +
             'EndSelection:00000000'   + #13#10;
var
    BodyStart : Integer;
    BodyEnd   : Integer;
    HdrLen    : Integer;
begin
    Result := Header;
    BodyStart := Pos('<BODY>', String(HtmlSrc));
    if BodyStart <= 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('<BODY> tag not found');
    Inc(BodyStart, 6);
    BodyEnd := Pos('</BODY>', String(HtmlSrc));
    if BodyEnd <= 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('</BODY> tag not found');

    HdrLen := Length(Header) - 1;
    WriteNumberIntoString(HdrLen,                   'StartHTML:',      Result);
    WriteNumberIntoString(HdrLen + Length(HtmlSrc), 'EndHTML:',        Result);
    WriteNumberIntoString(HdrLen + BodyStart,       'StartFragment:',  Result);
    WriteNumberIntoString(HdrLen + BodyEnd,         'EndFragment:',    Result);
    WriteNumberIntoString(HdrLen + BodyStart,       'StartSelection:', Result);
    WriteNumberIntoString(HdrLen + BodyEnd,         'EndSelection:',   Result);
    Result := Result + HtmlSrc;
end;

procedure WriteNumberIntoString(
    N        : Integer;
    const At : UTF8String;
    var S    : UTF8String);
var
    I : Integer;
    V : UTF8String;
begin
    I := Pos(At, S);
    if I <= 0 then
        Exit;
    I := I + Length(At);
    V := UTF8String(Format('%08.8d', [N]));
    Move(V[1], S[I], Length(V));
end;
```

With all that, the function to copy a HTML formatted data to the clipboard looks like:

```
procedure CopyHtmlToClipboard(const HtmlSrc : UTF8String);
var
    Svc      : IFMXExtendedClipboardService;
    Stream   : TStringStream;
    HtmlData : UTF8String;
const
    ClipFormat = 'HTML format';   // This is what Windows expect
                                  // Maybe other platform want something else
begin
    HtmlData := FormatHtmlForClipboard(HtmlSrc);
    Stream   := TStringStream.Create(HtmlData);
    if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(
                    IFMXExtendedClipboardService, Svc) then begin
        if not Svc.IsCustomFormatRegistered(ClipFormat) then
            Svc.RegisterCustomFormat(ClipFormat);
        Svc.SetCustomFormat(ClipFormat, Stream);
    end;
end;
```

You shall use the function like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    CopyHtmlToClipboard(
        '<!DOCTYPE><HTML><BODY><P>' +
        'This is a <b>bold</b> html line' +    //<== Your actual HTML text
        '</P></BODY></HTML>');
end;
```

Comment: Beautiful and wonderfully explained. Let me check with a quick fmx project and get back for any additional guidance. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works beautifully. My problem solved instantly. Marked this solution as Accepted Answer. Just a bit extra guidance, If I use this code for Unicode characters they are copied as ????. I changed all "AnsiString" with "String" but still not working. What else can be done here to make it Unicode compatible? Many Thanks.

Comment: @HilalSoftware About unicode: as I said, the HTML must use UTF8. You can use UTF8String instead of AnsiString. You must convert your strings (Unicode UTF16) to UTF8 if they content special characters. Pay attention that HTML rendering on the target application (Word or other) will no necessarily accept any character in-line. You should use HTML entities (See https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Comment: Solved. Problem lies with TStringStream as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557358/converting-an-ansistring-to-a-unicode-string
"TStringStream uses internally the default system ANSI encoding (1 byte per char)"

So in this regard changing create as follows removes the issue
Stream := TStringStream.Create(HtmlData,TEncoding.UTF8);// TEncoding.Unicode);

Could not work it out as TEncoding.Unicode but TEncoding.UTF8 is doing the job.

Comment: So in short to make above routines Unicode compatible we have to:
1. Declare all "AnsiString" as "String"
2. Create Stream with TEncoding.UTF8

Thank you very much for the help. Do I need to change the answer to make it Unicode compatible?

Comment: @HilalSoftware You may change all AnsiString by UTF8String (Wich is an AnsiString with CodePage 65001 anyway). The most important is when calling the top level function CopyHtmlToClipboard, pass an UTF8 encoded string. This would work but no guarantee that non US-ASCII character will be correctly rendered in the target application. As I said, better to stay with AnsiString and use HTML Entities. For example, in French, summer is "été". Correct way to represent this in HTML is "&eacute;t&eacute;". I'm sure you'll easily find Delphi code to convert a string to AnsiString with HTML entities.

Comment: @HilalSoftware I edited my answer to replace all AnsiString by UTF8String. If you need more help with UTF8String or with HTML entities, please ask a new question (First do some research by yourself to be sure to write a "good question" and avoid your question being "closed as duplicate" or "need details and clarity").

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Nothing more required now for problem at hand. UTF8String compatibility is a bonus. Stay blessed for your cooperation and help.